# LINQ error: variable 'x' of type 'y' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, linq, join, reference, subquery

I'm experiencing this error...

**variable 'paymentLine' of type 'Xrm.sb_directdebitpaymentline' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined**

... when I attempt to do 'paymentLines.ToList()' after the following code:

```
var payments = from payment in Crm.sb_directdebitpayments
               where payment.statuscode == 1
                     && Crm.sb_directdebitmandates.Any(mandate =>
                                                       mandate.sb_directdebitmandateid ==
                                                       payment.sb_directdebitmandateid &&
                                                       mandate.statuscode == 1)
               select payment;

var paymentLines = from paymentLine in Crm.sb_directdebitpaymentlines
                   where paymentLine.sb_paymentsent == isSent
                         && paymentLine.statuscode == status
                         && payments.Any(payment =>
                                         payment.sb_directdebitpaymentid ==
                                         paymentLine.sb_directdebitpaymentid &&
                                         payment.statuscode == 1)
                   select paymentLine;
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Is this LINQ to Objects, or LINQ To SQL, Entity Framework...?

Comment: I would think that if the query returns nothing after `Any()` and then you use `Select` that it would throw an error.

Comment: @Nick - it wouldn't. `Where` with `Any` will return empty sequence, `Select`ing from it will yield empty sequence, too, no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a curious combination of query syntax and extension methods (Any).

It looks like a variation on the *capture loop var* problem. Execution of  `paymentLines`  is deferred, so what value does the captured `paymentLine` line have when the `payments.Any( )` is executed?

Try to rewrite it as a Join.

Comment: Re-writing this as a join lead me to the correct answer, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had tried writing this as a join previously, but failed miserably.  However I revisited is today and worked out what I'd done wrong; it was to do with the order of the where clauses (indeed it took me a while to work out I even needed multiple where clauses!).  Thanks for all answers.  The solution was:

```
var paymentLines = from paymentLine in Crm.sb_directdebitpaymentlines
                   join payment in Crm.sb_directdebitpayments on paymentLine.sb_directdebitpaymentid equals payment.sb_directdebitpaymentid
                   join mandate in Crm.sb_directdebitmandates on payment.sb_directdebitmandateid equals mandate.sb_directdebitmandateid
                   where mandate.statuscode == 1
                   where payment.statuscode == 1
                   where paymentLine.sb_paymentsent == isSent && paymentLine.statuscode == status
                   select paymentLine;
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you cannot call `Any()` before a `Select` as `Any()` returns a `boolean` value. I would take all of the code you have inside the `Any()` and put it in the `Where` and then check for `Any()` before you `foreach` clause.

```
if (paymentLines.Any())
  {
foreach (var n in paymentLines)
         {
           //Do work
         }
  }
```