# exception: "variable 's' of type 'ClientRequest' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"

Tags: c#, serviceclient

I have a function to select a list of clients' requests from CRM by few conditions.

```cs
public static List<ClientRequest> funcion(CrmContext crmContext, Guid year)
{
    return (from s in crmContext.Xrm.allClientRequests
        where s.currentAccount != null
        && s.currentAccount.Id == s.lastAccount.Id
        && s.year.Id == year
        select s)
        .ToList();
}
```

but I got the exception: "variable 's' of type 'ClientRequest' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"

I searched in google and I understod that it is because this line:

&& s.currentAccount.Id == s.lastAccount.Id.

because the compiller doesn't know what is it 's' in the right side.
Am I right?
Is there someone that have idea how to fix it?
thank you so much!

Comment: Can you try writing it with the Linq method syntax?

Comment: Usually type names start with an upper case letter. Is the type name `ClientRequest`?

Comment: I dont know how to do it

Comment: `return crmContext.Xrm.allClientRequests.Where(s => s.currentAccount != null && s.currentAccount.Id == s.lastAccount.Id && s.year.Id == year).ToList();`

Comment: C# seems not to recognize the type `ClientRequest`. Are you missing a `using` declaration? Show us the class `ClientRequest`.

Comment: Mateus Zampol- I teied to change to linq and the exception left the same.

Comment: Olivier Jacot-Descombes- The exception is not because of it, the other functions with this type works well.

Comment: I have no idea how ServiceClient works, but maybe the expressions are being translated (similarly to how EF works). Can you try adding a `ToList()` before the Where clause?

Comment: You should read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5108680/22881459).